# Animation made of one big image

Tags: image, animation

I am wondering if there is any library to enable me to upload big image on website and than create animation.

**Animation description:**

Show are is smaller let's say `300*300` and image uploaded is `1024*768` and I would like the animation to go around the image, zoom out a little, zoom in, etc.

I hope I was clear enough.

Thanks for answers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This can be easliy done with the jquery function animate:
[jquery animate() doc](http://api.jquery.com/animate/)

They have some examples in their documentation. You can either work in a div with "overflow:hidden" and put the image in that div or set is as a background image. animate() allows you to manipulate the css styles. Also, you can append animate() calls.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Good idea! Thought about animating myself but wanted to ask if there is any other library... Because I want the animation to be randomized etc...